# Highchart Duplicate X-Axis and Y-Axis Labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am new to highchart. I have created simple chart for male and female count for last five years. I have attached the screen shot.

[image]

Is it possible to remove duplicate lables from both axis. ?

Here is the Code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    title: {
                        text: 'Male Female Count',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'Internet',
                        x: -20
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: 
                        [
                            <% 
                                for(ChartObject co : cos)
                                {
                                    out.print("'"+co.getMonth()+"',");
                                }
                            %>
                        ],
                        tickInterval: 4
                        //categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun','Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Year'
                        },
                        categories: 
                        [
                            <% 
                                for(ChartObject co : cos)
                                {
                                    out.print("'"+co.getYear()+"',");
                                }
                            %>
                        ],
                        tickInterval: 6
//                        plotLines: [{
//                                value: 0,
//                                width: 1,
//                                color: '#808080'
//                            }]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: ''
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'middle',
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    series: [{
                            name: 'Male',
                            data: 
                            [
                                <%
                                    for(ChartObject co : cos)
                                    {
                                        out.print(co.getMale()+","); 
                                    }
                                %>
                            ]
                        }, {
                            name: 'Female',
                            data: 
                            [
                                <%
                                    for(ChartObject co : cos)
                                    {
                                        out.print(co.getFemale()+","); 
                                    }
                                %>
                            ]
                        }]
                });
            });
        </script>
```

And dataset

[image]

Comment: Do you use categories or datetime type of axis?

Comment: You should set tickInterval as 12 on yAxis.

Comment: Its working but what about xAxis ?

Comment: If the y axis is a count of the values, why are you displaying the year in the y axis labels in first place?  It doesn't make sense, as the labels do not correspond to anything, and they hide the actual y axis values which would show you the count values that are displayed on the chart.

Comment: This should really be a chart with a 'datetime' x axis type instead of categories as well. Setting it up that way, without categories on either axis, will naturally solve both axes problems without further action.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should be 'normalizing' your dataset before rendering the chart.

Comment: should I change query ?

Comment: Could you please add your code to the post including the data you're trying to visualize? It will be easier to provide you with the correct answer.